# Having trouble with Jar in Intellij Idea

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea, awt, embedded-resource

Good evening! Thank you if you are reading this question. Sorry for the mistakes with grammar in the post.

I am having a problem with the *Executable Jar File* in Intellij Idea. The project contains some pictures, and I call them by using the JPanel. I expected it would display my pictures, but it wouldn't. It only shows me the text. I don't see any error message, and I follow some posts that talk about it, even that I try to use **Mark Directory as | Resources** but it doesn't work.

I find out that the file structure in the project and the .jar file are different. It doesn't include my resource folder and only show the files inside it. But, the class file have the path from the resource folder. Maybe that is the problem.

Can anyone show me how to build the.jar file without changing the file structure from project, or the way to display the images back to the .jar file?

***Thank all of you for reading this post***

```
public class WX_Class extends JFrame{
private static final long serialVersionUID=1;
public static void main(String[]args) {
    WX_Class WX = new WX_Class();
}
public WX_Class() {

    JPanel WX_Main = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    //Features
    JButton btn00 = new JButton("< Close tab");
    btn00.setBackground(Color.yellow);
    btn00.setForeground(Color.black);
    btn00.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
            dispose();
        }
    });
    JButton lb1 = new JButton("UbuntuVN Respin Tips", new ImageIcon("features_file//UbuntuVN_Respin.png"));
    lb1.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(400,200));
    lb1.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    JPanel WX_Box1 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(20,20));
    BoxLayout box = new BoxLayout(WX_Box1, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS);
    WX_Box1.setLayout(box);
    WX_Box1.setBackground(Color.white);
    WX_Box1.add(btn00);
    WX_Box1.add(lb1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    WX_Box1.add(new JLabel("Hello, welcome to the UbuntuVN Respin Tips"), BorderLayout.WEST);
    WX_Box1.add(new JLabel("Find somethings that you need here"), BorderLayout.WEST);
    JLabel wx_text1=new JLabel("Tips");
    wx_text1.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 20));
    WX_Box1.add(wx_text1, BorderLayout.WEST);
    WX_Main.add(WX_Box1, BorderLayout.WEST);
    JScrollPane WX_Scroll = new JScrollPane(WX_Box1);
    WX_Scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    WX_Main.add(WX_Scroll);
    JLabel WX_text2 = new JLabel("Title: UbuntuVN Respin - Design for Vietnamese users");
    WX_Box1.add(WX_text2);
    JButton WX_btn1 = new JButton("See the post");
    WX_btn1.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
    WX_btn1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            WX_Post1 post1 = new WX_Post1();
            post1.setVisible(true);
            dispose();
        }
    });
    WX_Box1.add(WX_btn1);
    WX_Box1.add(new JLabel("Title: Install UbuntuVN Respin"));
    JButton WX_btn2 = new JButton("See the post");
    WX_btn2.setBackground(Color.yellow);
    WX_btn2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            WX_Post2 post2 = new WX_Post2();
            post2.setVisible(true);
            dispose();
        }
    });
    WX_Box1.add(WX_btn2);
    WX_Box1.add(new JLabel("Title: Install, remove, troubleshoot software"));
    JButton WX_btn3 = new JButton("See the post");
    WX_btn3.setBackground(Color.yellow);
    WX_btn3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
            WX_Post3 post3 = new WX_Post3();
            post3.setVisible(true);
            dispose();
        }
    });
    WX_Box1.add(WX_btn3);
    //set Frame
    setTitle("UbuntuVN Respin Tips");
    WX_Main.setBackground(Color.white);
    this.setSize(800, 600);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setContentPane(WX_Main);
}
```

}

Comment: 1) **`new ImageIcon("features_file//UbuntuVN_Respin.png")` Passing a `String` to the constructor means it will assume it represents a `File`. A Jar does not contain files, but resources which must be loaded by `URL`. To get an `URL`, use the `getResource` method..** 2) `this.setSize(800, 600); .. this.setVisible(true); this.setContentPane(WX_Main);` should be `this.setContentPane(WX_Main);  this.pack(); this.setVisible(true);` 3) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` ..

Comment: .. unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently. 4) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). An MRE / SSCCE would be made much shorter bu having only the `lb1 button, no actions and using default layouts. It would also need the `import` statements. 5) See [Detection/fix for the hanging close bracket of a code block](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251795/155831) for a problem I could no longer be bothered fixing. Please [edit] the question to add 4 space chars ahead of the closing `}` at end of code.

Comment: Excuse me, how can I contact you? I want to ask for some more information about this method, please

Comment: *"..how can I contact you?"* You've already done so! If you mean for private communications or advice, then note that I'd only do that for a fee. Trust me, at my rates, you couldn't afford it.